# How to fix JavaScript syntax error using Umbraco?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, umbraco

I'm using Umbraco, trying to follow the Base tutorial as shown on the [website](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/developing-with-umbraco/base-and-ajax-development/introduction-to-base/TVPlayer#).

The following code gives me a syntax error in FireBug:

```
jQuery("#get").click(function() { 
        var pageId = <umbraco:Item field="pageID" runat="server" />;
          jQuery.get("/base/Sample/GetPageData/" + pageId + ".aspx", function(data){
            alert("Data loaded: " + jQuery(data).test());
          });
    });
```

I don't know if the umbraco code is causing the error but it is succesfully returning the pageId so the error reads as: Syntax Error: var pageId= 1007

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: Hope this helps clarify things, if not let me know!

Button I am setting up in umbraco template of page:

```
<asp:Button id="get" Text="getxml" runat="server" />
```

Although I have just realised that the rendered HTML of the button is a bit of a mess:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$get" value="getxml" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$get&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_get" />
```

Why is it doing this??

This is the jquery code as generated in the page:

```
 jQuery("#get").click(function()
        var pageId = '1082';
          jQuery.get("/base/Sample/GetPageData/" + pageId + ".aspx", function(data){
            alert("Data loaded: " + jQuery(data).test());
          });
    });
```

I included the enclosing single quotes as suggested but with or without I am getting the same Syntax Error in FireBug and my script is not working

Comment: Can you post the rendered output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button with the Id 'get' was being generated as `ContentPlaceHolderDefault_Get` for some reason (Umbraco?). So I changed the name in the get method to the generated name whilst leabing the button Id as get.

I guess this was a result of me writing the button control in an umbraco template rather than copying over from a .net control

Answer (score 2):

I think `pageId` is a string looking at your code so it should be enclosed in quotes. Try this.

```
jQuery("#get").click(function()
        var pageId = '<umbraco:Item field="pageID" runat="server" />';
          jQuery.get("/base/Sample/GetPageData/" + pageId + ".aspx", function(data){
            alert("Data loaded: " + jQuery(data).test());
          });
    });
```

Comment: Can you check the source and see what is rendered on the page at that place?

Comment: Can you put `alert('test get request')` before your alert in the `get` success handler and see if it works.

Comment: The id of the button is not being set to what I defined in the template. Instead this id is given to the button 'ContentPlaceHolderDefault_Get' as well as a whole load of other generated stuff (see edit in question) - I guess umbraco is doing this. I had already tried test alerts and nothing is coming up, which now that I have discovered a re-generated idea for the button explains...

Comment: alert not working. nor is changing the button id to the generated id that i mentioned above..